# Can I force merge index in Mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query looking like

```
SELECT fld from table
WHERE id > 50000 
AND fld_1 = 0 
LIMIT 1000
```

Both id and fld_1 are indexed. But its always using either one of them together for better result? Force index is using only one of them.

I am referring - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-intersection

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way to force an index-merge.  The conditions on that manual page describe the conditions when an index-merge can be done, and the optimizer should do it automatically if it can (and if the cost-based optimizer decides it's worth it to do so).  You can't force an index-merge if it's not possible.

But a compound index usually performs better than index-merge anyway, so that would be a  better strategy.

The order of columns matters.  Put the columns for *equality* comparisons first in the index, then columns for *inequality* comparisons.

```
CREATE INDEX idxFld1Id ON `table` (fld_1, id);
```

See also my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

---

You can make schema changes such as creating indexes -- without downtime -- by using http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html

Of course, first try it on a test copy of your database, to learn how to use the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As of now adding an index is almost impossible for me as it will required few hours of downtime. So I was trying to make use of existing indexes. If I create index on (fld1, id) there is more probabilty of picking the index as cardinality is too high and I am bit concerned whether it will be used even when some other index is suppose to be used.

Comment: @BillKarwin, What's the disadvantages of "pt Online Schema Change"?

Comment: @Pacerier, pt-online-schema-change is slower than using a conventional ALTER TABLE. It requires the table have a primary key and do not have triggers. Otherwise, it doesn't have much disadvantage. I suggest you watch the webinar by its author, see [Zero-Downtime Schema Changes in MySQL](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-05-02-zero-downtime-schema-changes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try below by replacing your index name 
SELECT fld from table use index (`xxx`)
WHERE id > 50000 
AND fld_1 = 0 
LIMIT 1000

Comment: It doesnt work. I have tried force index too. But only one of the index will be used, not the both

Comment: Yes, I did. If i say force index(index_1), it will never use index_2. I know that.